# How to pass a composable function without a lamda?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

```
Scaffold(
           bottomBar = { SootheBottomNavigation() },
           content = { padding ->
           HomeScreen(Modifier.padding(padding))
       }
       ) 

   @Composable
    fun HomeScreen(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    
         
    }
```

How do you pass content composable without the lambda into Scaffold?
Below is the parameter for Scaffold

```
content: @Composable (PaddingValues) -> Unit
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve? the same functionality with different aesthetics? or do you want to omit the Scaffold's content?

Comment: I want to learn how to pass functions without lambdas. I'm confused. This doesnt work for composable functions ( https://play.kotlinlang.org/byExample/04_functional/01_Higher-Order%20Functions)

Comment: yes same functionality with different aesthetics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question...

I think you want to do this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ScreenContent(paddingValues: PaddingValues) {
    Text("Hello")
}

@Composable
fun MyScreen() {
    Scaffold(
        content = ::ScreenContent // ERROR here
    )
}
```

But seems like this is not supported, since this error is displayed:

> "Function References of @Composable functions are not currently
> supported"

An alternative would be:

```kotlin
val ScreenContent: @Composable (PaddingValues) -> Unit = { it ->
    Text("Hello")
}

@Composable
fun MyScreen() {
    Scaffold(
        content = ScreenContent
    )
}
```

But to be honest, I would go with the regular lambda calls...

```kotlin
@Composable 
fun ScreenContent(paddingValues: PaddingValues) { 
    Text("Hello")
}

@Composable
fun MyScreen() {
    Scaffold(
        content = { ScreenContent(it) }
    )
}
```